# Identify window.scroll event when it triggered by user OR by an code executed by an event

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

DO we have a way to identify whether `window.scroll` event has been triggered by   a user mouse OR by calling an function on some event.
I am using ES6, Typescript with angular.

I do see that this question has been asked in the past related to jQuery and the proposed solution, pasted below, does NOT work now anymore. `e.originalEvent` is always there no matter how the scroll has been triggered.

```
$('#scroller').scroll(function(e) {
    if (e.originalEvent) {
        console.log('scroll happen manual scroll');
    } else {
        console.log('scroll happen by call');
    }
});
```

Comment: is the function yours that is fireing the scroll event programmatically. If yes then how? by using the jquery animate or what else.

Comment: @localhost yes, function is mine. when user clicks on an link, I fire that function and scroll to an specific section related to that link. I am using "windows.location.hash" for this. NOT using jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the mouse **wheel event**, `onwheel`, to detect if scroll was initiated by mouse or not.

However, this is solely limited to the situation when the user scrolls the mouse wheel while having the cursor inside the container in question and **will not address the problem when the user grabs and moves the scrollbar or when the scroll is triggered by up or down key presses**.

A better approach could be to reverse the logic how the `isWheel` flag in handled in the below snippet, and use an `isNotWheel` flag that is set/unset by those handlers that are triggered programmatically and will scroll the container contents.

Note, that `timer` and `Set/ClearTimeout` is utilized in the example to adequately support Frefox which only emits the wheel event once at the start of a mouse scroll in contrast with Chrome which emits both the wheel event and the scroll event throughout the duration of the scroll movement.

```js
$(() => {

  const main = document.getElementsByTagName('article')[0];
  const a = document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
  let isWheel = false;
  let timer = null;
  
  $(main).scroll( e => {
    clearTimeout(timer)
    timer = setTimeout(() => {
      isWheel = false;
    }, 100);
    
    if (isWheel) {
      console.log('Scroll triggered by mouse wheel');
    } else {
      console.log('Scroll NOT triggered by mouse wheel');
    } 
  });
  main.addEventListener('wheel', e => {
    isWheel = true;
  });
  
  $(a).click( e => {
    main.scrollTo(0, 0);
  });
  
})
```

```css
.main {
  height: 150px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article class="main">
<div>
 scroll me
</div>
<div>
 scroll me
</div>
<div>
 scroll me
</div>
<div>
 scroll me
</div>
<div>
 scroll me
</div>
<div>
 scroll me
</div>
<div>
 scroll me
</div>
<div>
 scroll me
</div>
<div>
 scroll me
</div>
<div>
 scroll me
</div>
<div>
 scroll me
</div>
<div>
 scroll me
</div>
<div>
 scroll me
</div>
<div>
 scroll me
</div>
<div>
 scroll me
</div>
<div>
 scroll me
</div>
<div>
 scroll me
</div>
<div>
 scroll me
</div>
<div>
 scroll me
</div>
<div>
 scroll me
</div>
<div>
 scroll me
</div>
<div>
 scroll me
</div>
<div>
 scroll me
</div>
<div>
 scroll me
</div>
<div>
 scroll me
</div>
<div>
 scroll me
</div>
<div>
 scroll me
</div>
<div>
 scroll me
</div>
<div>
 scroll me
</div>
</article>
<a href="javascript:void(0);">Trigger scroll by "function"</a>
```